# Error - "IR Hardware not detected" - but it's installed/working

Tags: windows-xp, windows-media-center, tv, media-center, satellite

I am trying to do: Settings->TV->Set up TV signal.  During this process I am getting the error "IR Hardware not detected."  With the remote, I can select the "try again" button (to re-detect) and it tries again, so the remote works. Plugging in the "IR blaster" doesn't change anything. (I wouldn't expect any difference, but I read a post which said you needed that. I will get Media Center to change channels if I can get that working - but first things first.)

I was able to do the setup months ago when I had cable. and everything
was fine. I just got DirecTV. (BTW - During the above process, Media Center detects the signal coming in on channel 3. Windows XP Media Center SP3. The TV Tuner card is a Pinnacle
TCTV HD PCI. Everything - and I mean everything - has the latest firmware and drivers - as of 4 months ago when I fixed a different problem. So I DON"T WANT TO HEAR the standard answer to check drivers/firmware. THANK YOU.)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed this problem too: [Media Center setup won't complete for watching TV](https://superuser.com/questions/131277/media-center-setup-wont-complete-for-watching-tv)